# Google hangouts with drive realtime collaboration

Tags: google-drive-api, google-plus, google-drive-realtime-api

We have an app working with google drive realtime, and thought that it might be nice to include it as a hangout collaboration option.

I can't seem to find any nice way of coordinating authorisation for drive realtime documents with hangout participants.

Has anyone done something like this? Ideally some way to automatically share a drive document with all hangout participants, so that the hangout app can then just connect to the drive realtime stream.

(We already looked at hangouts shared state but this is too limited for our use case)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to insert permissions objects using only a Google+ ID. However, if the participants of the hangout have their email address listed in their profile, you can use the [Hangouts API](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout#gapi.hangout.Participant) to get the Google+ ID of the participants, and then use the [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) to get the email addresses of participants, which you can then use when inserting new permissions for the file.